# Renaming minified JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

Is there some type of script or website that accepts minified JavaScript code (with all the variable names replaced with a, b, c, d, e, etc.) and returns "unminified" JavaScript, either by intelligently guessing the names or randomly assigning easily memorable names such as blueGiraffe2 or similar?

Comment: The very first result in google for "unminify javascript" ?

Comment: to change vars to something meaningful would be an extraordinary feat of coding

Comment: Please use correct terminology. Minification and obfuscation are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that can *unobfuscate* variables (give them meaningful names). However, you can easily *unminify* JavaScript in many ways:

1. Most IDEs have a code formatting feature that you can use
2. Chrome has a "pretty print" feature on the bottom left of a minified source file.
3. Firefox has a "pretty print" feature on the bottom right of a minified source file

However, it will be hard to figure out what the code does; it's minified and obfuscated for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Found something that does exactly what I asked for here. http://jsnice.org/